# Strange usage of find() in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Learning the use of find() in Matlab from [here](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) and [here](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html), I came across the following usage, but could not find the explanation of the functioning of the code.

```
X = [0.00000   0.00000   0.00000;
     4.24264   0.00000   0.00000;
     8.48528   4.24264   0.00000]

[A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3)] = find(X)
```

This evaluates to :

```
A =
    2.0000   1.0000   4.2426                                                                                                                              
    3.0000   1.0000   8.4853                                                                                                                              
    3.0000   2.0000   4.2426
```

The find() function should return a column vector, but how is the matrix A getting initialized without error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html):

If you specify three output variables:

```
[row,col,v] = find(X)
```

find returns the row and column subscripts of each nonzero element in array `X` and vector `v`, which contains the nonzero elements of `X`.

```
row =

     2
     3
     3


col =

     1
     1
     2


v =

    4.2426
    8.4853
    4.2426
```

In your case, these three vectors are assigned to the columns of matrix `A`.